# Unable to install ADT on Eclipse 4.2

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've looked through many similar threads which seem to range from changing settings to changing https to http to attempting to install manually.

Trying to install ADT 20.0.0 on Eclipse 4.2 Juno gives me [this](http://www.hawnutor.org/image/8AMSuhD.png) error.

All items apart from Android Developer Tools install with no issue, although when including download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/ on the software sites I get frozen at [this](http://www.hawnutor.org/image/qKnB2CQ.png) stage for a while (Note: it's been stuck there for about 5 minutes currently), then proceeds to give the earlier error.

The problems are the same whether using archive/local/link and extracting the items and running with -clean didn't change anything either.

Is there anything else I could try to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS do you have?  The error says you're missing the Java Development of Core. http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/

Comment: I had to switch to the Java EE version of Eclipse and then remove http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/ from software sites since that's where it kept on freezing, and then it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I ended up having to revert back to an earlier version of eclipse to get things to work. I did a fresh install and everything, but could not get the ADT plugin to work until I switched back.